# In multiple arraylist i want duplicate values rename

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I tried this code for if i have  duplicate string in multiple `arraylist` it update `1_Maths,2_Maths`

e.g.
in multiplearraylist i have

> maths
>
> english
>
> maths
>
> hindi
>
> english

**so i want o/p:**

> 1_Maths
>
> 1_english
>
> 2_Maths hindi
>
> 2_english

My code is this for generate array list

```
Dim col As Integer = 0
Dim dt As New DataTable

Dim ArraySubject(0, Grd.Columns.Count - 1) As String
For i As Integer = 0 To Grd.Columns.Count - 1
   If Grd.Columns(i).Visible = True Then
      ArraySubject(0, col) = GvSearch.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text 
      col += 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer in c# would also help me.

Comment: How do you get "2_Maths hindi"??? This is a terrible, terrible question. Extremely unclear.

Comment: @ThomasW It seems formatting problem I just corrected

Comment: What you tried for achieving this post that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much VB.NET, so here's what I think you want in C#:

```cs
string[] subjects = new string[] { "maths", "english", "maths", "hindi", "english" };

Dictionary<string, int> subjectCounts = new Dictionary<string, int> ();
foreach (string subject in subjects) {
    if (subjectCounts.ContainsKey(subject))
        subjectCounts[subject]++;
    else
        subjectCounts.Add(subject, 1);
}

List<string> output = new List<string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in subjectCounts) {
    if (pair.Value > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= pair.Value; i++)
            output.Add(i + "_" + pair.Key);
    } else {
        output.Add(pair.Key);
    }
}

foreach (string subject in output)
    Console.WriteLine(subject);
```

This outputs:

> 1_maths
>
> 2_maths
>
> 1_english
>
> 2_english
>
> hindi

If you want it sorted by number, just sort the array before outputting it.

```
output.Sort();
```

Output:

> 1_english
>
> 1_maths
>
> 2_english
>
> 2_maths
>
> hindi

Comment: foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in subjectCounts) {
    if (pair.Value > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= pair.Value; i++)
            output.Add(i + "_" + pair.Key);
    } else {
        output.Add(pair.Key);
    }
}This loop giving error for subjectCounts is not convert type string to double

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<string> list = new List<string>();
private List<string> rslt = new List<string>();            
list.Add("math");
list.Add("science");
list.Add("math");
list.Add("science");

foreach (string i in list)
{
     rslt.Add(i);
}
foreach (string i in list)
{
     if (list.Count<string>(f => f == i) > 1)
     {
          int cnt = 1;
          int idx = 0;
          foreach (string j in list)
          {
               if (j == i)
               {
                    rslt[idx] = cnt.ToString() + "_" + j;
                    cnt++;
               }
               idx++;
           }
      }
 }
```